# Team City Fails to Build Dot Net Core, But Manual Build Works

Tags: .net-core, teamcity

I have a nuget package that I am updating to multi-target (including DotNet Core 2.
2).

I set it up in Team City and I get an error when I run the build.

So I logged into the build server to try to build from Visual Studio.  The manual build succeeded!

So I tried my team city build again, and it Succeeded!

Suspicious of this, I checked the "delete everything before build" box, and it failed again! Same error!

So this seems to be a Team City thing.  Here is the first of MANY error messages it gives me:

> D:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\.NETStandard,Version=v2.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs(4, 20): error CS0400: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)

It seems like every target I have builds fine for the full Dot Net Framework.  But my one target for DotNet Core (2.2) fails.  (Again, it works fine when I login to the machine and build it manually from Visual Studio.)

**Any idea what I can do to have Team City build my DotNet Core solution?**

Here is the summary view of my build step:

[image: Visual Studio Build Step]

Comment: Can you share build step definition from TeamCity and command which you used to build locally on the build server?

Comment: @Rob, I added an image that has the parameters of my build step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into this I saw lots of answers relating to doing a NuGet restore.  But my solution did not have any nuget packages.

But DotNet Core comes in via NuGet.

Once I added a build step to do that, it worked fine.